# How can I scan the number in this file without scanning the the char?

Tags: c

I am going to save the ids of those students who failed their test `score<60`
I tried to make it but it dosen't work. It stopped after I typed the name of file.
Where is the problem? Thank you!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    int i=0, j=0, count=0;
    int id[500], score[500], fail[500];
    char fname1[128], rbsh[100];
    
    scanf("%s", fname1);
    FILE *f1 = fopen(fname1, "r");
    
    fscanf(f1, "%s", rbsh);
    while(1){
        
        fscanf(f1, "%d ", &id[i]);
        fscanf(f1, "%d\n", &score[i]);
        i++;
        count++;
        if(feof(f1)){
            break;
        }
    }
    
    fclose(f1);
    
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        if(score[i]<60){
            fail[j] = id[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<j; i++){
        printf("%d ", fail[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the inputs...
.csv file

```
ID,score
1,25
2,77
3,88
4,100
5,100
6,44
7,10
8,69
9,70
10,35
11,69
```

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step through your program.

Comment: Where in your code do you believe you're skipping over the commas?

Comment: Oooooh!!! I missed the comma!! Thank you so much ;-;

Comment: I thought that the space after %d will help me to skip the commas

Comment: It will skip whitespace but no comma

Comment: せいが, Rather than `if(feof(f1))`, check the return values of `fscanf()`.